# How do I use AWS SNS in laravel 5.2?

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, laravel-5, amazon-sns

I want my application to send SMS messages to other mobile numbers. I got to know that I need to create a topic, then a subscriber and later publish messages to all the subscribers. But I am not getting how to implement all this stuff like creating topic, subscribers and publishing messages in laravel 5.2 programmatically.

Answer (score 2):

Use this library from amazon team

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel

Documentation
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-sns-2010-03-31.html

Comment: Thanks bro! But I wanted to know how to use the sdk in laravel like for creating topic, subscribers, publish message, etc.